# NSIS RegFree, Component ... not correctly registered ... Win10(x64) or Win7(x64)

Tags: vb6, nsis, windows-7-x64, ocx, regfreecom

I have had my NSIS script files working for a while 32 bit ...
On a fresh (Not used for Development) Win7/Win10 (64), there are problems with the .OCX files.

The programs and their support files are installed in C:\Program Files (x86)... or D:\Program Files (x86)...
This includes: Program.exe, Uninstall.exe, .dll, .tlb, .olb, .ocx and their .manifest files.
My installations are 'RegFree'.
Their data files are located in: C:\Users\Public... or D:\Users\Public...

I get the error message when I start the program, newly installed on a Win7(x64) or Win10(x64) PC:

Component 'RICHTX32.OCX' or one of its dependencies not 
correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid

Depending on the program, this has complained about: MSCOMCT2.OCX, threed32.ocx or RICHTX32.OCX

I ran Dependency Walker in the deployment environment e.g.: Win10(64)
for RICHTX32.ocx. It created a listing in the left-hand panel:

SHELL32.DLL
OLEDLG.DLL
KERNEL32.DLL
USER32.DLL
0LE32.DLL
ADVAPI32.DLL
OLEAUT32.DLL
COMDLG32.DLL
GD132.DLL

KERNEL32.DLL is the only one of the first line of dependents with red flagged items in the right hand panel.

I updated the NSIS script to include KERNEL32.DLL with the other support files copied to the C:\Program Files (x86)...

I still get the error message:
Component 'RICHTX32.OCX' or one of its dependencies not 
correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid

Any ideas for how to succeed in my RegFree installation. Please?

That is the way I started out, without KERNEL32.DLL . I get the error message with or without it. – user243281

I wish I had an answer for how to prepare my installations to work on Win7(x64) and Win10(x64). They put things in the correct folders, but do not run.

I created this application with VB6 on a WinXP(32) virtual PC. I also compiled the NSIS script in the same development environment. I had believed my work was done, but my test installs were on PCs 'contaminated' by development activities.
-------------- My QueryMgr Manifest:

? I inserted 4 blanks in front of each line if the manifest (XML) but it would not accept it?

I cannot get it to accept the QueryMgr Manifest.  It is an XML file, but not close enough to HTML...?

All of the manifest files are installed in the install directory e.g.: C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\

I tried pasting the manifest files in the main posting window, but they are code...?  (XML files that are similar to HTML)

The .OCX files are probably a part of my VB6 development environment. Probably related to form controls I have used in the applications. One of them, threed32.ocx, is ~3rd party ?Attachment? to VB6.

--------------------- NSIS script:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
  ;create a InstallDirectoryRequirements Page vvvvvvv
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"
!include "winmessages.nsh"
!include "logiclib.nsh"
!include "x64.nsh"          ;14jul2013
  ;create a InstallDirectoryRequirements Page ^^^^^^^
;!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_SMALLDESC ;No value
;?!define MUI_UI "myUI.exe" ;Value
;!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_COLORS "FFFFFF 000000" ;Two colors

; -------------------------------
; Start


  !define MUI_PRODUCT "QueryMgr"
  !define MUI_FILE "QueryMgr"
  !define MUI_VERSION "2.08"
  !define MUI_BRANDINGTEXT "QueryMgr Ver. 2.08"
  CRCCheck On

 !include "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Modern UI\System.nsh"

 ;--------------------------------
;General

  Name "QueryMgr ${MUI_VERSION}" 
  OutFile "iQueryMgr.exe"
 ;Default installation folder
;  InstallDir "$LOCALAPPDATA\Clark_Anderson\${MUI_PRODUCT}"
;  InstallDir "C:\Users\Public\Clark_Anderson\${MUI_FILE}"

  !include winver.nsh

;11aug2013  var /GLOBAL DATADIR             ;31jul2013
  var  DATADIR              ;11aug2013

  ShowInstDetails "nevershow"
  ShowUninstDetails "nevershow"
  ;SetComInstallDirectoryRequirementsssor "bzip2"

;?  !define MUI_ICON "icon.ico"
;?  !define MUI_UNICON "icon.ico"
  !define MUI_SPECIALBITMAP "Bitmap.bmp"
 ;--------------------------------
;Folder selection page
;  InstallDir "C:\Users\Public\Clark_Anderson\${MUI_PRODUCT}"

;11aug2013 xxxxx vvvv 
;Function dir_pge_txt_dest
;       !define $MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION "Setup will install ${MUI_PRODUCT} ${MUI_VERSION} in the Following folder. To install in a difFerent folder, click Browse and select another Folder. Click Install to start the installation.  It is imperative to install into the C:\Users\Public\... folder structure! "
;FunctionEnd  
;11aug2013 xxxxx ^^^^ 
;07aug2013 vvvvvvvvvvvv
Function .onVerifyInstDir
    ${If} ${RunningX64}                 
    ${Else}
        StrCpy $DATADIR $INSTDIR
    ${EndIf}                            
FunctionEnd 
;07aug2013 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 


;--------------------------------
;Modern UI Configuration

  !define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE  
  !define MUI_LICENSEPAGE
  !define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE

  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING
  !define MUI_UNINSTALLER
  !define MUI_UNCONFIRMPAGE
  !define MUI_FINISHPAGE 

Function .onInit
  ${If} ${AtLeastWinVista}
    ${If} ${RunningX64}                 
      StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES32\Clark_Anderson\${MUI_FILE}"
      ExpandEnvStrings $DATADIR "%PUBLIC%\Clark_Anderson\${MUI_FILE}"   
    ${Else}                             
      ExpandEnvStrings $INSTDIR "%PUBLIC%\Clark_Anderson\${MUI_FILE}"   
      ExpandEnvStrings $DATADIR "%PUBLIC%\Clark_Anderson\${MUI_FILE}"   
    ${EndIf}                            
  ${Else}
    StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES\Clark_Anderson\${MUI_FILE}"
    StrCpy $DATADIR "$PROGRAMFILES\Clark_Anderson\${MUI_FILE}"    
  ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd  


 ;--------------------------------
;Pages

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
;  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\License.txt"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
  Page custom InstallDirectoryRequirements ;"Important Information About Install Location"      ;create a multi-line edit (text) control

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

  ;create a InstallDirectoryRequirements Page vvvvvvv

    !define InstallDirectoryRequirements_TITLE "Requirements for the ${MUI_PRODUCT} Install Directory"
    !define InstallDirectoryRequirements_SUBTITLE "This is to permit access to ${MUI_PRODUCT} by all PC Users $\r$\nand prevent interference to and from other programs on your PC. " 

var Dialog
Var Label

Function InstallDirectoryRequirements
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "${InstallDirectoryRequirements_TITLE}" "${InstallDirectoryRequirements_SUBTITLE}"
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
        Pop $Dialog
        ${If} $Dialog == error
            Abort
        ${EndIf}

        Pop $INSTDIR
        ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 20% "Setup will install ${MUI_PRODUCT} ${MUI_VERSION}  in the Following folder: $\r$\n     $INSTDIR $\r$\n"  ;To install in a different folder, on the next page click Browse and select another Folder, then, Click Install to start the installation.  "
        ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 15% 100% 30% "Setup will install ${MUI_PRODUCT} Sample Data  in the Following folder and its subfolders: $\r$\n     $DATADIR $\r$\n"  ;To install in a different folder, on the next page click Browse and select another Folder, then, Click Install to start the installation.  "  ;31jul2013
        Pop $Label
;       ${NSD_AddStyle} $Label ${SS_CENTER}

        ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 30% 100% 40% "The ...\Clark_Anderson  subfolder identifies the source of the program.$\r$\nThe ...\${MUI_PRODUCT} subfolder is unique to this program.$\r$\n$\r$\nEverything needed by ${MUI_PRODUCT} is stored in this ..\${MUI_PRODUCT} subfolder and its subfolders.$\r$\n$\r$\nThis 'Everything needed' is achieved by including manifest files (reg-free COM),$\r$\n thus, refraining from use of the PC Registry."
        Pop $Label
;       ${NSD_AddStyle} $Label ${SS_CENTER}

  ${If} ${AtLeastWinVista}
    ${If} ${RunningX64}     ; 03aug2013 vvvv
        ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 80% 100% 40% "It is imperative to install into the C:\Program Files (x86)\... folder structure! "
        Pop $Label
    ${Else}                 ; 03aug2013 ^^^^
        ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 80% 100% 40% "It is imperative to install into the C:\Users\Public\... folder structure! "
        Pop $Label
    ${EndIf}                    ; 03aug2013
;       ${NSD_AddStyle} $Label ${SS_CENTER}
  ${EndIf}
  ${If} ${RunningX64}       ; 14jul2013 vvvv
        ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 90% 100% 40% " 64 bit windows, tested."
        Pop $Label
  ${Else}
        ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 90% 100% 40% " 32 bit windows, well tested."
        Pop $Label
  ${EndIf}                  ; 14jul2013 ^^^^

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

;Section ""
;SectionEnd  
  ;create a InstallDirectoryRequirements Page ^^^^^^^

;--------------------------------
;Language

  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"


;-------------------------------- 
;Modern UI System

;?  !insertmacro MUI_SYSTEM 


;--------------------------------
;Data

;  LicenseData "Lees_mij.txt"

;-------------------------------- 
;Installer Sections  
InstType "Compact"   
InstType "Typical"

;Add files
Section "Program Files"
  SectionIn 1 2
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

  File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\QueryMgr\QueryMgr.exe"
SectionEnd

Section "System Files - WinSysDir"
  SectionIn 1 2
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVBVM60.dll"
  File "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.OLB"
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\stdole2.tlb"
  File "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACC9.OLB"
  File "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll"
  File "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6EXT.OLB"
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\msstdfmt.dll"
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMDLG32.OCX"
  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\RICHTX32.OCX"

;18aug2017  File "C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll"   ; 12aug2017

    File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\QueryMgr\Manifest\QueryMgr.exe.manifest"
    File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\_dllManifest\MSVBVM60.dll.manifest"
    File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\_dllManifest\VB6.OLB.manifest"
    File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\_dllManifest\stdole2.tlb.manifest"
    File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\_dllManifest\MSACC9.OLB.manifest"
    File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\_dllManifest\dao360.dll.manifest"
    File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\_dllManifest\VB6EXT.OLB.manifest"
    File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\_dllManifest\msstdfmt.dll.manifest"
    File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\_dllManifest\COMDLG32.OCX.manifest"
    File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\_dllManifest\RICHTX32.OCX.manifest"

; 12aug2017    File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\_dllManifest\kernel32.dll.manifest"


SectionEnd

Section "Sample Data Files (Optional: Recommended for starting)"
  SectionIn 2
 SetOutPath "$DATADIR\DataBases"
  File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\QueryMgr\Databases\ASQLSela2k.mdb"
  File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\QueryMgr\Databases\ASQLJoi22k.mdb"
  File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\QueryMgr\Databases\ASQLJoi3.mdb"
  File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\QueryMgr\Databases\ASQLFcn42k.mdb"
  File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\QueryMgr\Databases\ASQLUni62k.mdb"
  File "c:\Devlpmnt\LANG\VB6\QueryMgr\Databases\LookUp.mdb"
SectionEnd

;Installation info
Section "install"
  SectionIn 1 2

;create desktop shortcut
;  CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\${MUI_PRODUCT}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MUI_FILE}.exe" ""
  CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\${MUI_FILE}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MUI_FILE}.exe" ""

;create start-menu items
  CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\${MUI_PRODUCT}"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${MUI_PRODUCT}\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe" 0
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${MUI_PRODUCT}\${MUI_PRODUCT}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${MUI_FILE}.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\${MUI_FILE}.exe" 0

;write uninstall information to the registry
  WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${MUI_PRODUCT}" "DisplayName" "${MUI_PRODUCT} {remove only}"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${MUI_PRODUCT}" "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

SectionEnd

;--------------------------------    
;Uninstaller Section  
Section "Uninstall"
;12aug2013  variable $DATADIR values not saved for this section vvvv
    ${If} ${RunningX64}                 
        ExpandEnvStrings $DATADIR "%PUBLIC%\Clark_Anderson\${MUI_FILE}" 
    ${Else}
        StrCpy $DATADIR $INSTDIR
    ${EndIf}                            
;12aug2013  variable $DATADIR values not saved for this section ^^^^

;Delete Files 
  Delete "$INSTDIR\*.*"                     ;12aug2013
  Delete "$DATADIR\Reports\Templates\*.*"   ;12aug2013
  Delete "$DATADIR\Reports\*.*"             ;12aug2013
  Delete "$DATADIR\DataBases\*.*"           ;12aug2013
  Delete "$DATADIR\*.*"                     ;12aug2013

;Remove the installation directory
;13aug2013 +vvvv
  RMDir $INSTDIR
  RMDir $DATADIR\Reports\Templates
  RMDir $DATADIR\Reports
  RMDir $DATADIR\DataBases
  RMDir $DATADIR
;13aug2013 +^^^^

;Delete Start Menu Shortcuts
  Delete "$DESKTOP\${MUI_PRODUCT}.lnk"
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\${MUI_PRODUCT}\*.*"
  RmDir  "$SMPROGRAMS\${MUI_PRODUCT}"

;Delete Uninstaller And Unistall Registry Entries
  DeleteRegKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\${MUI_PRODUCT}"
  DeleteRegKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${MUI_PRODUCT}"  

SectionEnd
;--------------------------------    
;MessageBox Section


;Function that calls a messagebox when installation finished correctly
Function .onInstSuccess
  MessageBox MB_OK "You have successfully installed ${MUI_BRANDINGTEXT}. Use the desktop icon to start the program."
FunctionEnd


Function un.onUninstSuccess
  MessageBox MB_OK "You have successfully uninstalled ${MUI_BRANDINGTEXT}."
FunctionEnd

;!verbose 0
;!error ""
;eof
```

(I hope this NSIS script came through as clean code, after my editing to insert the 4 spaces)

[Simplest is Query manager](http://net.indra.com/~anderci/ciaartcl.htm)

===============================
RICHTX32.OCX  seems to need kernel32.dll

C:>dir /s kernel32.dll
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 48C7-50D7

Directory of C:\Windows\System32

05/30/2017  01:39 PM           708,712 kernel32.dll
               1 File(s)        708,712 bytes

Directory of C:\Windows\SysWOW64

05/30/2017  01:39 PM           599,576 kernel32.dll
               1 File(s)        599,576 bytes

Directory of C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-kernel32_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.15063.0_none_a4d1be7a8f1a4216

05/30/2017  01:45 PM            19,984 kernel32.dll
               1 File(s)         19,984 bytes

Directory of C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-kernel32_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.15063.296_none_289f5225bcc26659

05/30/2017  01:39 PM           708,712 kernel32.dll
               1 File(s)          708,712 bytes

Directory of C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-kernel32_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.15063.0_none_af2668ccc37b0411

05/30/2017  01:55 PM               7,072 kernel32.dll
               1 File(s)            7,072 bytes

Directory of C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-kernel32_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.15063.296_none_32f3fc77f1232854

05/30/2017  01:39 PM             599,576 kernel32.dll
               1 File(s)          599,576 bytes

The install PC (win10(64)) has 6 different copies of kernel32.dll .  How is my application supposed to know which one to use?

My virtual development PC (WinXT(32)) has these two copies of richtx32.ocx:
C:>dir /s RICHTX32.OCX
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F432-F929

Directory of C:\Program Files\Clark_Anderson\QueryMgr

03/09/2004  12:00 AM               212,240 richtx32.ocx
               1 File(s)          212,240 bytes

Directory of C:\WINDOWS\system32

03/09/2004  12:00 AM               212,240 RICHTX32.OCX
               1 File(s)          212,240 bytes

My 'tainted' host development PC Win7(x64) has these copies of richtx32.ocx:
C:>dir /s RICHTX32.OCX
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 70F2-883E

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\QueryMgr

03/09/2004  12:00 AM               212,240 richtx32.ocx
               1 File(s)          212,240 bytes

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Tools\VB\Controls\Controls_Backup

03/09/2004  12:00 AM               212,240 RICHTX32.OCX
               1 File(s)          212,240 bytes

Directory of C:\Windows\SysWOW64

02/16/2010  03:22 PM               218,432 richtx32.Ocx
               1 File(s)          218,432 bytes

The unsuccessful install PC Win10(x64) has only the copies installed by the NSIS script e.g.:
C:>dir /s richtx32.ocx
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 48C7-50D7

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\QueryMgr

03/09/2004  12:00 AM              212,240 RICHTX32.OCX
               1 File(s)         212,240 bytes

Does anyone know the significance of this?  My efforts to use the reg-free install is to prevent my applications from interfering with other applications and permitting a clean uninstall, again not interfering with other applications and data.

I created the test application, requested, One Form with its one RichTextbox control. Its manifest is in one of the comments, below:
The NSIS script is the way I have for creating an install of an application on another PC.

I have very little experience with windows 10. I did find the event viewer. I do see a few errors in Windows Logs/System: DistributedCOM eventID 10016 But only occurred once(2) since I installed the zRichTx application (not for the several times I tried to run it)

In the same way I found an error: Windows Logs/Application: Application Error EventID 1000 Task Category (100), but it does not respond to an uninstall , install and a few attempts to run the application that all end in the same error message: Component RICHTX32.ocx not correctly registered ...

I am over my head with parts of the installing my VB6 applications on (x64) Windows 10 and Windows 7.  That is why I came asking help from the experts.

```
=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
  Flags = 0
  ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32
  CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
  ManifestPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\zRichTx\zRichTx.exe.Manifest
  AssemblyDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\zRichTx\
  Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\zRichTx\zRichTx.exe.Manifest.
  INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is zRichTx.exe,type="win32",version="2.4.0.14".
  INFO: Reference: stdole2.tlb,type="win32",version="5.1.2600.5512"
  INFO: Reference: RICHTX32.OCX,type="win32",version="6.1.97.82"
INFO: Resolving reference stdole2.tlb,type="win32",version="5.1.2600.5512".
  INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture stdole2.tlb,type="win32",version="5.1.2600.5512".
    INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
      INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
        INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
      INFO: Begin assembly probing.
        INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
        INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\zRichTx\stdole2.tlb.DLL.
        INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\zRichTx\stdole2.tlb.MANIFEST.
        INFO: Manifest found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\zRichTx\stdole2.tlb.MANIFEST.
      INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference stdole2.tlb.mui,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="5.1.2600.5512".
  INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture stdole2.tlb.mui,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="5.1.2600.5512".
    INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
      INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
        INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
      INFO: Begin assembly probing.
        INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
        INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
      INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
      INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
        INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
      INFO: Begin assembly probing.
        INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
        INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
      INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference RICHTX32.OCX,type="win32",version="6.1.97.82".
  INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture RICHTX32.OCX,type="win32",version="6.1.97.82".
    INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
      INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
        INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
      INFO: Begin assembly probing.
        INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
        INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\zRichTx\RICHTX32.OCX.DLL.
        INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\zRichTx\RICHTX32.OCX.MANIFEST.
        INFO: Manifest found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\zRichTx\RICHTX32.OCX.MANIFEST.
      INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference RICHTX32.OCX.mui,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="6.1.97.82".
  INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture RICHTX32.OCX.mui,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="6.1.97.82".
    INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
      INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
        INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
      INFO: Begin assembly probing.
        INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
        INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
      INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
      INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
        INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
      INFO: Begin assembly probing.
        INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
        INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
      INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\zRichTx\stdole2.tlb.MANIFEST.
  INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is stdole2.tlb,type="win32",version="5.1.2600.5512".
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files (x86)\Clark_Anderson\zRichTx\RICHTX32.OCX.MANIFEST.
  INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is RICHTX32.OCX,type="win32",version="6.1.97.82".
INFO: Activation Context generation succeeded.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

You were right.  I found how to open a cmd prompt with admin.  These were the results. Does it make any sense to you?

You were right. I found how to open a cmd prompt with admin. Above are the results. Does it make any sense to you?

I am running out of time. My Windows10(x64) test PC will be going away, very soon.  On my Windows7(x64) test PC, the SXStrace parsed file is empty?  If I logon as Administrator the zRichtx program works?!

I created an administrator logon on the Windows10(x64) test PC... running zRichtx there gets the same error msg, but SXStrace, again comes up empty?!

Comment: KERNEL32.DLL is a system component, you don't have to do anything with it and including it in a installer is absolutely wrong!

Comment: You did not post any NSIS code and more importantly, you did not post your manifest file nor did you tell us where these .ocx files are from! Are they from VB6 or some 3rd-party?

Comment: I have updated the primary window content (except for manifest files - XML)  How can I post a manifest file?

Comment: There are in some ways only two copies of kernel32, a 32-bit file and a 64-bit file. Files in WinSxS is for the side-by-side feature and are only used when requested by a manifest. A 32-bit application will load kernel32 from c:\windows\syswow64 on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="RICHTX32.OCX" version="6.1.97.82" />
  <file name="RICHTX32.ocx">
     <typelib
        tlbid="{3B7C8863-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}"
        version="1.2"
        helpdir=""/>
    <comClass progid="RichText"
       clsid="{3B7C8863-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}"
       description="ActiveX Control" />
  </file>
</assembly>

Comment: The last 'comment' is the manifest for the richtx32.ocx.  Is it correct?  I cannot remember what side-by-side is.  Has the information, I have provided, clarified my initial question?

Comment: I'm talking about your .manifest for your .exe where the regfree details are.

Comment: Then you need to reduce the size of the code required to reproduce the problem. Start a new project and only use the problematic richedit ocx.

Answer (score 0):

Take NSIS out of the equation, it is not relevant to the problem at hand.

I think the best way to solve the problem is for you to diagnose it on your own.

Start a new VB project and just add the problematic OCX control and the minimal required amount of code to reproduce the problem on the machine with the issue. Then [look at the event log and run SxSTrace](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2006/04/14/diagnosing-sidebyside-failures/) to try to figure out why it cannot find the component...

Comment: Here is the manifest you asked for            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="zRichTx.exe" version="2.4.0.14" />
 <dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="stdole2.tlb" version="5.1.2600.5512" />
  </dependentAssembly>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="RICHTX32.OCX" version="6.1.97.82" />
  </dependentAssembly>
 </dependency>
 </assembly>

Comment: What about SxSTrace?

Comment: Run as admin probably?

Comment: I have moved my earlier comments up into the main window. Something has changed.  I do, now, have an administrator login. sxstrace runs and  continues to come up empty?  Does the existence of an admin login thwart fruitful running of sxstrace?